# SQLAlchemy how to define two models for the same table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a single table, and one of the columns is a varchar with two values ('groupA','groupB')

When I created my models I wanted to achieve two things:

1. model for groupA - that hold X amount of related functions
2. model for groupB - that hold Y amount of related functions

the functions are not the same for both models, though they represents the *same* table:

```
class GroupA(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'groups' 

  id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
  name  = Column('name',  String(80))
  group_type = Column('type', String(15), default="groupA")
```

And for groupB:

```
class GroupB(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'groups' 

  id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
  name  = Column('name',  String(80))
  group_type = Column('type', String(15), default="groupB")
```

So GroupA & B are the same table: "groups", but GroupA has 100 rows, groupB has 20rows

I want to prevent writing this all the time:

```
session.query(GroupA).filter(group_type = 'groupA')
session.query(GroupB).filter(group_type = 'groupB')
```

How can I configure my model with some kind of a "fitler" that when I'll query.all() it will return the data relavent for each model ? right now I receive all data in both models no matter which model I queried...

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT with the solution based on answer

To use inheritence I had to change the entire structure to

```
class Group(Base):
   id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
   name  = Column('name',  String(80))
   group_type = Column('type', String(15))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': g_type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'Group'
    }

# Replacing Base => Group
class GroupA(Group):
   __mapper_args__ = {
      'polymorphic_identity': 'GroupA'
   }

class GroupB(Group):
   __mapper_args__ = {
      'polymorphic_identity': 'GroupB'
   }
```

And it's working, thank you very much !

Comment: I am not experienced with SQLAlchemy but it seems that you need this: [Mapping a Class against Arbitrary Selects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-arbitrary-selects)

Comment: And it will act the same thing as a regular model ? like when I query one row - and update its value - it updates the matching row in the DB, right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance) is what you need. Define your `group_type` as the polymorphic identity and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks ! this is what I need, though I'm unable to configure it on GroupB, it gives me an error for GroupA: AssertionError: No such polymorphic_identity u'groupA' is defined

Comment: Both models need polymorphic identity, look at the example in docs. If SQLAlchemy encounters a value in group_type that it doesn't know about, it throws that error.

Comment: I think I understand my problem, Group A or B don't inherit from each other as opposed to the example in your link, where either manager/eng are considered "employees"

Comment: If I define polymorphic identity, it throws an error: Table 'groups' is already defined for this MetaData instance. Specify 'useexisting=True' , can you plz show me an example of how you would write it ? for Group A& B