# SQLAlchemy: Creating two classes (models) for the same table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am interacting with a database with a star schema. I have a fact table that depends on a dimension table in two different ways.

When writing SQL by hand, I join the dimension table twice under different names. I want to do the same thing in SQLAlchemy.

After reading the docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393889/sqlalchemy-how-to-define-two-models-for-the-same-table) thread, what I have is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, TIMESTAMP, Float, ForeignKey, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relation, sessionmaker, synonym, aliased

Base = declarative_base()

class RBase(Base):
    __tablename__ = "regions"
    # id
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=True)
    # Dimensions
    region = Column("region", String, nullable=True)
    _all_dimensions = ()


class Regions(RBase):
    # Dimensions
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'Regions'
    }


class OtherRegions(RBase):
    # Dimensions
    otherregion = synonym("region")
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'OtherRegions'
    }


class FactTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "somefact"
    # Dimension ids
    sourceregionid = Column(
        "sourceregionid", Integer, ForeignKey("regions.id"), primary_key=True, nullable=True
    )
    targetregionid = Column(
        "targetregionid", Integer, ForeignKey("regions.id"), primary_key=True, nullable=True
    )
    # Facts
    examplefact = Column("examplefact", Float, nullable=True)
    # Relations
    region = relation(Regions, innerjoin=True, foreign_keys=[sourceregionid])
    otherregion = relation(OtherRegions, innerjoin=True, foreign_keys=[targetregionid])
```

The statement I'm getting from this is

```
SELECT regions.region, somefact.examplefact
FROM somefact 
JOIN regions ON regions.id = somefact.sourceregionid 
JOIN regions ON regions.id = somefact.targetregionid 
WHERE regions.region = %(region_1)s
```

which causes and error. What I want is

```
SELECT regions.region, otherregions.region as otherregion, somefact.examplefact
FROM somefact 
JOIN regions ON regions.id = somefact.sourceregionid 
JOIN regions as otherregions ON otherregions.id = somefact.targetregionid 
WHERE regions.region = %(region_1)s
```

I have spent a while going in circles about this, so any help would be much appreciated.